# importar modulo completo en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Tengo una carpeta llamada `Command` donde guardo un script `suma` con el siguiente codigo:

```py
def suma_1(a, b):
    return a+b
```

y quiero llamarlo desde un script en la masma carpeta que `Command` de esta manera:

```py
import os
print(os.path.pardir)

import Command
print(Command.suma.suma_1(1, 3))
```

incluí `os` como ejemplo en la parte superior, porque de esa misma manera quiero importarlo. El problema es que me tira error advirtiendo que no exite `suma` en `Commando`

```py
..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/joaqu/OneDrive/Escritorio/Informatica/ZZZ_CosasImportantes/Python/Importan/Terminal/prueba3.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(Command.suma.suma_1(1, 3))
AttributeError: module 'Command' has no attribute 'suma'
```

Puedo de alguna manera importarlo sin necesariamente escribir el nombre del script?

Intente tambien con `from Command import *` pero no funciono

Comment: Para que la carpeta se comporte como un paquete (una colección de módulos) debe incluir un fichero llamado `__init__.py`, que puede estar vacío. Por otro lado mejor no usas nombres de paquetes (carpetas o scripts) que usen mayúsculas, porque según en qué operativo estés podrían confundirse con otros de igual nombre pero sin mayúscula.

Comment: ya agregue `__init__.py` al fichero pero no funciono.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realmente tratas de importar un paquete, no un módulo. Antes de Python 3.3 (solo paquetes regulares) era necesario agregar un archivo `__init__.py` vacío en el directorio que conforma el paquete para que Python lo trate como tal. A partir de Python 3.3 (introdución de los paquetes de espacio de nombres) no es necesario hacer esto de forma explícita ([Implicit Namespace Packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/)) para que Pyton lo considere como un paquete.

Como supongo que usas Python >= 3.3, Python ya trata `Command` como un paquete. El problema real es que cuando importas `Command`, el intérprete busca los directorios en PYTHONPATH hasta que encuentra el directorio pero no escanea ese directorio recursivamente e importa automáticamente todos los archivos .py que encuentra. Es decir, `suma.py` no es importado.

Tienes varias opciones:

- **Sin hacer uso del archivo `__init__.py` (paquete de espacio de nombres) o usando un archivo `__init__.py` vacío (paquete regular):**

  ```
  import Command.suma
  print(Command.suma.suma_1(1, 3))
  ```

  o bien:

  ```
  from Command import suma
  print(suma.suma_1(1, 3))
  ```
- **Haciendo uso de un archivo `__init__.py` con contenido:**

  Crea un archivo llamado `__init__.py` dentro de `Command` y añade la línea:

  ```
  from . import suma
  ```

  Ahora ya puedes importar tal como hacías en tu código:

  ```
  import Command
  print(Command.suma.suma_1(1, 3))
  ```

  El archivo `__init__.py` se ejecuta implícitamente y los objetos que se definen en el mismo quedan vinculados a nombres en el espacio de nombres del paquete.

Comment: Muchas gracias.